# Pyspark Cumulative sum within Partition for moving last 2 (N) rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cumulative-sum, partition-by

Let's say I have the following dataframe which is sorted for ease visually:

[image]

How would I utilize window functions to create a new column that sums the previous row ordered by `Month` column within each `period` partition:

[image]

The following is my attempt at it, but I'm obviously doing something wrong with respect to the `rowsBetween` function.

```
df = df.withColumn('CustLast2', sum('Cust').over(Window.partitionBy("period").orderBy('Month').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, -1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to sum the last 2 rows (current row included), so simply specify the `rowsBetween` like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Period').orderBy('Month').rowsBetween(-1, Window.currentRow)

df = df.withColumn('CustLast2', F.sum('Cust').over(w))
```

You inverted the lower and upper bounds of the window frame in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost their, you just have to replace `-1` by `Window.unboundedPreceding`

```
df = df.withColumn('CustLast2', sum('Cust').over(Window.partitionBy("period").orderBy('Month').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))
```

Otherwise you're just doing the sum on 2 consecutive rows within the same period.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this?  If I wanted the window to be 6 or 7 or any arbtrirary number, how could I do this?

Comment: @ben890, that's what `Window.unboundedPreceding` is for, it's going to look back for all the current partition.

Comment: This won't even execute. You can't specify the boundary end of the frame as `Window.unboundedPreceding`

Comment: @blackbishop, I'm using it in many pipelines so you can, but it might not be what you need though. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween.html

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc Can you show complete example using `.rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedPreceding)`? I'm curious.. Maybe you mean `Window.unboundedFollowing` for the upper bound?

Comment: @blackbishop, apologies I see what you mean the argument where inverted. I've edited the post. `Window.unboundedFollowing` won't gibe you the same result though.

Answer (score 0):

We made the [Fugue project](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue) to port native Python or Pandas code to Spark or Dask. This lets you can keep the logic very readable by expressing it in native Python. Fugue can then port it to Spark for you with one function call.

First we start with a test Pandas DataFrame (we'll port to Spark later):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"] * 3, 
                   "period": [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   "val": [4,5,2] * 3})
```

Then we make a Pandas based function. Notice this is meant to be applied per group. We will partition later.

```py
def rolling(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["cum_sum"] = df["val"].rolling(2).sum().fillna(df["val"])
    return df
```

Now we can use the Fugue transform function to test on Pandas. This function handles the partition and presort also.

```py
from fugue import transform
transform(df, rolling, schema="*, cum_sum:float", partition={"by":"period", "presort": "date asc"})
```

Because this works, we can bring it to Spark just by specifying the engine:

```py
import fugue_spark
transform(df, rolling, schema="*, cum_sum:float", partition={"by":"period", "presort": "date asc"}, engine="spark").show()
```

```
+----------+------+---+-------+
|      date|period|val|cum_sum|
+----------+------+---+-------+
|2020-01-01|     0|  4|    4.0|
|2020-01-02|     0|  5|    9.0|
|2020-01-03|     0|  2|    7.0|
|2020-01-01|     1|  4|    4.0|
|2020-01-02|     1|  5|    9.0|
|2020-01-03|     1|  2|    7.0|
|2020-01-01|     2|  4|    4.0|
|2020-01-02|     2|  5|    9.0|
|2020-01-03|     2|  2|    7.0|
+----------+------+---+-------+
```

Notice you need `.show()` now because of Spark's lazy evaluation. The Fugue transform function can take in both Pandas and Spark DataFrames and will output

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using the code below:

```
(df.withColumn('last_value', F.lag(F.col('Cust')).over(W.partitionBy(['Period']).orderBy(F.col('Month'))))
   .withColumn('last_value', F.when(F.col('last_value').isNull(), 0).otherwise(F.col('last_value')))
   .withColumn('cumSum', F.col('Cust') + F.col('last_value')))
```